# Aligning input field and buttons

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I'm trying to align two buttons to ad input field but I end up messing everything every single time. 
I've already aligned an input field to a single button, but I'm not able to add a second button. 
**This is the html (I'm using some angularjs):**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <form class="form" ng-submit="vm.reCreateTree(ricercaSecondario)" ng-init="aggiornaRicercaPratica()">
            <div class="input-group">                               
                <input type="text" ng-model="vm.cercaSecondario" class="form-control" placeholder="{{getTestoPlaceholderRicerca(ricercaPraticaSecondario)}}" required="required" ng-disabled="disabilitaRicercaSecondaria()">
                   <div class="input-group-btn">
                       <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>  
                       <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"
                            tooltip="Espandi filtri di ricerca" tooltip-placement="bottom"
                            ng-click="toggleRicerca()" ng-show='user.ambitoSelezionato.nome == "Clienti-Polizze"'>
                       <i ng-class="{'fa fa-caret-up': showEspandiRicerca, 'fa fa-caret-down': !showEspandiRicerca}"></i>
                       </button>
                  </div>    
           </div>                            
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

**This is a screenshot of the result:**
[image]

As you can see the two button are not in the same line as the input field and they are also uneven (speaking about dimensions)... 
Any help?!

**UPDATE: updated the code (thanks to Mukesh Ram) but the buttons still have two different sizes..**

[image]

Comment: You can use Bootstrap's [grid system](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) and [input groups](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups) cto align in single line with same width.

Comment: So you need to search icon and arrow icon button have some width? Right?

Comment: yeah. I'd like them to have the same width

Answer (score 1):

You can have multiple buttons inside a single `.input-group-btn`. Like this:

```
<div class="col-lg-6"> 
    <div class="input-group">
       <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Text input with multiple buttons"> 
       <div class="input-group-btn"> <!-- add button in this div -->
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" aria-label="Help">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign"></span>
         </button>
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Action</button> 
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm upvoting this because you solved half of my problem. The buttons still have two different sizes...

Comment: So, you have to fixed the width of buttons. Like this: `.form .input-group-btn button{ width:39px;}`

Comment: I don't use css and there are other input-group-btn so I can't place it in header. Isn't there a property that takes care of the width of the buttons?!

Answer (score 1):

*One other way :* 
`form-inline` and `form-group`

**Bootply** : http://www.bootply.com/uHEpGIOLwY

```
 <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <form class="form-inline" ng-submit="vm.reCreateTree(ricercaSecondario)" ng-init="aggiornaRicercaPratica()">
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" ng-model="vm.cercaSecondario" class="form-control" placeholder="{{getTestoPlaceholderRicerca(ricercaPraticaSecondario)}}" required="required" ng-disabled="disabilitaRicercaSecondaria()">
            <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
            <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit" tooltip="Espandi filtri di ricerca" tooltip-placement="bottom" ng-click="toggleRicerca()" ng-show='user.ambitoSelezionato.nome == "Clienti-Polizze"'>
              <i ng-class="{'fa fa-caret-up': showEspandiRicerca, 'fa fa-caret-down': !showEspandiRicerca}"></i>
            </button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I've a preference for @MukeshRam answer... But just for the diversity of answers, I post this one....